# Gremlin.Net: Message with op code [close] is not recognized

Tags: c#, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinnet

I am trying to run this query against AWS Neptune Db using Gremlin .Net client and I getting an exception with message.

`Message with op code [close] is not recognized`.

Is there something wrong in this code?

```
var query = graph.V().Values<string>("resourceId").Dedup();
using (var uniqueResourceIds = query.Project<string>("resourceId"))
{
    var queryResult = await uniqueResourceIds.Promise(x => x.ToList());
} // No error while awaiting the response. Getting the error when the execution of code is moving forward from the "using" block.
```

Comment: What is `graph`?  Is that a Graph object or GraphTraversalSource object?  Overall, how are you defining the connection to Neptune?

Comment: Also, can you please post the full error message?